# the pic of the body get hover

Tags: css, developer-tools, angular-fullstack

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXBAW.png)i hope you can be easy with me cause i am new in full stack developer. i start a course from Udemy and i arrived at part of img background. i tried to put bottom with hover and when i pass with the Mouse on the bottom the pic background go up with the hover of the bottom anyone can help me to fix it?  i hope you will understand my English is no my Native language

I tried to hover only the bottom with box shadow and color and when i pass with the mouse on the bottom it hover up but the pic of the body background get up too

Comment: Can you please give some of code to show us is better to help you acurately

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i edited the post can you see now?